# Detected the current OS's ImageIO PNG Decoder is buggy on indexed color PNG. Perform workaround solution?

Tags: swift, swiftui, png

I am trying to use `SDWebImageWebPCoder` and `SDWebImage` in my SwiftUi project.

the code is working fine on `gif/webp/jpeg` images except `png` images :

```
WebImage(url: URL(string: account.image))
                                .onSuccess { image, data, cacheType in
                                    // Success
                                    // Note: Data exist only when queried from disk cache or network. Use `.queryMemoryData` if you really need data
                                }
                                .resizable()
                                .indicator(.activity)
                                .transition(.fade(duration: 0.5))
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .frame(width: 140, height : 140, alignment: .center)
                                .background(Color("place_holder_bg"))
                                .clipShape(Circle())
```

the PNG images is not displayed and I am getting warning in console instead :

```
Detected the current OS's ImageIO PNG Decoder is buggy on indexed color PNG. Perform workaround solution...
```

I am loading the coders on App load :

```
import SwiftUI
import SDWebImage
import SDWebImageWebPCoder

@main
struct APP: App {
    
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
    @StateObject var env:Env = Env.shared
    
    init(){
        SDImageCodersManager.shared.addCoder(SDImageAPNGCoder.shared)
        SDImageCodersManager.shared.addCoder(SDImageWebPCoder.shared)
        SDImageCodersManager.shared.addCoder(SDImageGIFCoder.shared)
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            w_tabs()
                .environmentObject(env)
                .preferredColorScheme(env.theme)
        }
    }
}
```

also I've updated the pod repo still same issue! any idea why ?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to use that specific library? If not you may want to have a look at [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) which also seem to support gifs (and png of course) or Apple's own AsyncImage (but I don't know if it supports gifs).

Comment: I am using it for animated and none animated `webp` images I am not sure if kingfisher also support webp animated images! will check it out

Comment: I think I used it once for webp too